# How do I fix this error code in google play console?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, in-app-subscription

This was the error I got

"
An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (598B272F)
"

Comment: Same error here when trying to update my notification settings and it can't save the changes I've made.

Comment: I recieve the same when I try to do anything... : An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (53E8B4C3)

Comment: My error was supposedly an issue with needing to set something up, like a prerequisite for what I was trying to do.